# Python XMLRPC and https

Tags: python, magento, ssl, https, xmlrpclib

I'm using Python 2.7.9 on Mac os x yosemite.

I'm using the following module to post updates to our Magento install via their API. [Github Magento Python XMLRPC](https://github.com/voberoi/python-magento)

It works fine using a normal HTTP connection to my test server, however, when I try to migrate to our live server, this uses HTTPS exclusively.
We have a SHA256 SSL EV certificate.

The connection string I'm using is:

```
from magento import MagentoAPI
magento = MagentoAPI("www.mywebsite.co.uk", 80, "username", "api_key", "/api/xmlrpc", True)
```

The error I get is:

```
SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:581)
```

I've tried adjusting the port to 443, and also setting the protocol to HTTPS

However, fails all the time.

I'm afraid i'm new to python so this one has me stuck.

Comment: Are you sure you need to connect to port 80 and not port 443?

Comment: The [source code hardcodes `http`](https://github.com/voberoi/python-magento/blob/master/magento/__init__.py#L17), you'll have to ask the project maintainers to consider HTTPS.

Comment: I've tried port 443, and I've over-ridden to HTTPS.

Comment: Where are you setting the protocol, exactly?

Comment: And can you give us the *full* traceback of your exception?

Comment: I've just run this again with Port = 443 and HTTPS , and its gone through. - I'm going to try and investigate a bit more as this did not work before and gave the SSL error.